# Is SMTP protocol only for sending?

Tags: smtp

Is it possible to use SMTP as described in [**RFC 5321**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) to receive mail or is it prohibited by this spec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SMTP is used only for sending mail - transferring mail to mail servers, and between mail servers. POP and IMAP are two popular protocols (but not the only protocols) for mail user agents (end-user email clients) to retrieve mail, which I'm guessing is what you're asking about.

To put it a different way, an SMTP conversation is initiated by software that wishes to *transmit* email to another device. It's not usually used as the last-hop step to *deliver* email to a user - those conversations are usually initiated by software that wishes to receive the email.

Comment: A more proper distinction is that SMTP is a *transport* protocol, not a *delivery* protocol. Surely, in order for a sending SMTP server to connect anywhere, there must be receiving servers, too.

Answer (score 0):

### ESMTP extensions for email receiving

SMTP is used to receive email servers listed in MX recerds from "all internet".

If you want to use it to receive your email from relay accepting emails from "all internet":

- with static IP address but without permanent internet connection you may use [ETRN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ETRN#ETRN) command [[RFC-1985](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1985)]
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ETRN#ETRN
- with dynamic IP address you may use [ATRN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-Demand_Mail_Relay) [[RFC-2625](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2645)]
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-Demand_Mail_Relay

Both extensions are designed for "for domain emails" not for "single mailbox emails".